# How to specifiy the java/android platform with IntelliJ-IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I wanted to try out IntelliJ-IDEA but my experiments failed in a very early state. The Problem is that I found no way to set the Java platforms to be used.

Standard Java fails `@Override` annotation as IntelliJ-IDEA fails to to use the installed Java 6.

Android tells me to set the Android platform - only there is no setting so be seen to set any platform.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use File -> Project Structure menu.

There you can specify jdk(by New button you can add your installed jdk).
In your android module settings(Project Structure : Modules) click the detected facet( Android ) and there choose your platform.

Comment: Thanks. Worked well. I would never had expected the option there.

Answer (score 0):

Please [refer to the official documentation](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA). Also be aware of [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-62526).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However I was importing existing (Maven) projects and not creating new projects. I guess I should have mentioned that.